# how can I report on report types in salesforce

Tags: reporting, administration

I have accumulated scores of custom reports types within my org and some of them I think are obsolete, therefore I would like to remove them, however, in the interest of integrity, I would like to make sure that no reports are based on the report type that I want to delete, therefore I am looking for a way of reporting of the reports by report type so that I can find out this information.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a custom report type of the report object that will include the report type as a field - then create a report using this custom report type.  This report will be able to list the report types of all the reports.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch all reports to Force.com IDE (if you have LOADS of reports try to do it couple folders at a time - the metadata API can retrieve 5K objects in one go).

Then Ctrl+H (or any non-Eclipse "find in files" of your choice) and search for the report type API name.

Reports that use it will have line similar to

```
    <reportType>Custom_Objects_with_More_Objects__c</reportType>
```

This sounds like a lot of hassle but probably you should backup the reports anyway before this purge so ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no relationship between Report (`00O`) and ReportType (`070`) unfortunately.

I looked at metadata for [Report](https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php?default_object=Report) and [ReportType](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDescribeAndList.php?type=ReportType) in Workbench and couldn't find any junctions either.

Can you take the reports from 'Deployed' back to 'In Development' and see who complains? ;-)